# How to make this regex accept decimals also

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression like this

```
/^[0-9]*\s*kg\s*[0-9]*$/
```

This accepts strings like `100 kg` or `100kg`. I am tring to make it also accept `100.1kg` or `100.1 kg` or `10,20 kg` and so on (both dot and decimal should be accepted). How do I change that current regex so that those numbers I mentioned also tests true? I have seen this regex which supports  numbres and decimals but I am unsure how to combine it with my regex.

```
^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it optional you could use an optional non capturing group `(?:` and add matching 0+ times a whitespace after it:

```
^[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?\s*kg$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lkFSnI/1)

Now it will match

- `^` Start of the string
- `[0-9]+` 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[,.][0-9]+` match comma or dot and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\s*kg` Match 0+ times a whitespace character
- `$` End of the string

Answer (score 2):

For incorporating decimal values optionally in addition to whole number values, you can just place this regex `(?:[.,]\d+)?` after `^[0-9]*` which will allow it to support decimal values like you mentioned in your post. Overall regex becomes this,

```
^\d*(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*kg\s*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/am3TXQ/2)